# Why does second condition override the first in If/Then statement in my excel VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel

My If statement within a For Each loop isn't working. When the ElseIf condition (message box "2") is satisfied, even if the first condition (message box "1") is satisfied, "2" always appears and that code runs. When I remove the code after ElseIf ("2"), then "1" appears and that code runs. Essentially, The second condition seems to override the first condition's code. I know that the second condition is more general, but it doesn't explain why the first condition is skipped even though it's definitely satisfied (proven when I remove the second condition). Any thoughts as to why the second condition takes over?

```
For Each curr In Range("A2:Z10")
        If InStr(1, curr.Value, "Protein name", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, curr.Value, "description", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            MsgBox ("1")
            Range(curr.Offset(1), Cells(Rows.Count, curr.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("ExtractedColumns").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            Exit For
        ElseIf InStr(1, curr.Value, "protein", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            MsgBox ("2")
            Range(curr.Offset(1), Cells(Rows.Count, curr.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("ExtractedColumns").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot, or a sample of the data that is being traversed with this script please

Comment: Probably "protein" comes first in your data in `A2:Z10`. your code basically finds the first occurrence of either of the three strings, and shows the `msgbox` accordingly. after this the loop stops

Comment: I just realized what the problem might be... because column A is titled "Protein" and it's only looking at that cell in the first iteration, it skips to the second condition. Only later is the first condition, "Protein name", satisfied (it's the header of column F). I'll try to fix this by splitting the For Each loop into two - one for each condition.

Comment: @nightcrawler23 you posted while I was writing- that's what I was thinking. Thanks!

Comment: the question is why do you have the `Exit For` inside your `For Each` loop ? Do you really only wanna copy the first occurrence one of these values is found within the first cell in `Range("A2:Z10")` ?

Comment: Remove `Exit For` on both `iF's` then run it, also screenshot will be helpful...

Comment: @Shai Rado and 0m3r I only want to copy the first occurrence of the values, and I've tried it with and without the Exit For (and it works better with the Exit For).